# Split string in SQL server 2012 in a row

Tags: sql-server, string, split, delimiter

The string is in

```
@txt nvarchar(max)='2450,10,54,kb2344,kd5433;87766,500,100,ki5332108,ow092827'
```

And I want output like this:

`Id.         Val1.     Val2.       Val3.             Val4.          Val5.`
 `1.          2450      10          54                kb2344         kd5433.`
`2.          87766     500         100               ki5332108      ow09287`

Can anybody suggest how to do that?

I google it , and found this solution. But it is for two comma separated values but in my case there are five:

```
 DECLARE @Var NVARCHAR(100) = '2450,10,54,kb2344,kd5433;87766,500,100,ki5332108,ow092827'
 SELECT LEFT(@Var, CHARINDEX(';', @Var) - 1) ,SUBSTRING(@Var, CHARINDEX(';', @Var) + 1, LEN(@Var)- LEN(LEFT(@Var, CHARINDEX(';', @Var)))- LEN(RIGHT(@Var, CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE(@Var))))) AS [Job] , RIGHT(@Var, CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE(@Var))-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming values 1-5.  This can easily be done with a little XML in concert with a CROSS APPLY

If the number columns are variable, you would have to go DYNAMIC.

> **EDIT - Changed to nvarchar**

**Example**

```
Declare @txt  nvarchar(max)='2450,10,54,kb2344,kd5433;87766,500,100,ki5332108,ow092827'

Select ID=A.RetSeq
      ,B.*
 From (
        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null)) 
              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')))
        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@txt ,';','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
      ) A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Val1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)')))
                      ,Val2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)')))
                      ,Val3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)')))
                      ,Val4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','nvarchar(max)')))
                      ,Val5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','nvarchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(A.RetVal,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as B1
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4        Val5
1   2450    10      54      kb2344      kd5433
2   87766   500     100     ki5332108   ow092827
```

Comment: @AbuHassan Happy to help